# Resolving "Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow" Spark exception

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

I am trying to run Spark (Java) code and getting the error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 27".
```

Other posts have suggested setting the buffer to its max value. When I tried this with max buffer value of 512MB I got the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.buffer.max', '512'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: While doing a spark-submit, use --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512m"

Answer (score 4):

Try using "`spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb`", "`512`" instead **`spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max`**", "**`512MB`**"

Answer (score 4):

The property name is correct, `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max`, the value should include the unit, so in your case is 512m.

Also, dependending where you are setting up the configuration you might have to write `--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512m`. For instance, with a `spark-submit` or within the `<spark-opts>...</spark-opts>` of an Oozie worflow action.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but the first hit when I googled, so answering here to help others.

For Spark 3.2 (in Azure Synapse environment, but not sure if that matters) I tried all of these combinations but the only one that worked to convert a large spark DataFrame toPandas() was `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512`. No letters after the number, no ".mb" at the end.

Comment: Hi 8forty- could you provide a little more detail on what you did? I'm in the same situation with Synapse and changing the configuration settings in a notebook where the session is already started seems to be a bit different.

Comment: @CodyDance I added the setting to the "Apache Spark Configuration" of the spark pool, so it's already set for all workers/notebooks that use the pool.

Answer (score 0):

either you can set this in spark configuration while creating spark session as

```
SparkSession.builder
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512m")
```

or you can pass with your spark submit command as

```
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--name "JOB_NAME" \
--master MASTER_IP \
--conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512m" \
main.py
```