# Understanding Kryo serialization buffer overflow error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I am trying to understand the following  error and I am running in client ode.

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 61186304. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value.
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Basically I am trying to narrow down the problem.
Is my understanding right that this error is occurring in the spark driver side(i am on aws emr so I believe this will be running on master)?
and I should be looking at `spark.driver.memory` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the problem is that kryo does not have enough room in its buffer. You should be adjusting `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` in your properties file, or use `--conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=128m"` in your spark-submit command.  128m should be big enough for you.

Comment: see this question for more information too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709770/org-apache-spark-sparkexception-kryo-serialization-failed-buffer-overflow-sp